# Rotating GeoTIFF images

Tags: geotiff-tiff, rasterio, numpy, rotate

I have a GeoTIFF file which when imported using rasterio get flipped on the y-axis, and now I am trying to rotate this GeoTIFF file using NumPy rotate, it gives an error (Axes=(0, 1) out of range for array of ndim=0)

```
rf = rasterio.open(r'C:\Users\NESAC\tp.geotif')
fig, ax= plt.subplots(1,1)
show(rf, ax = ax, title = 'temperature')
rot = np.rot90(rf, k=3)
```

[image: Original]

[image: Flipped]

Comment: your problem is no solved by rotation, you need to invert the direction of the y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Check your array dimensions using `rf.shape`. Try to skip `axis` [parameter](https://www.w3resource.com/numpy/manipulation/rot90.php):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]])
print(a, '\n')

b = np.rot90(a)
print(b, '\n')

c = np.rot90(a, axes=(0, 1))
print(c)

error = np.rot90(a, k=1, axes=(1, 2))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/sessions/635a4f4228bcccc0/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    error = np.rot90(a, k=1, axes=(1, 2))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 128, in rot90
    .format(axes, m.ndim))
ValueError: Axes=(1, 2) out of range for array of ndim=2.
```